How to display range of records based on startdate and enddate ASP.NET web app
POST EDITED
Have a backend API that displays a range of records based on the StartDate and EndDate.  The backend action (GetRange) looks like this:
    [HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetRange([FromQuery] DateRange dataRange)
{

    var range = _context.Products.AsQueryable();
    DateTime startdate = dataRange.StartDate.Value.Date;
    DateTime enddate = dataRange.EndDate.Value.Date;

    if (dataRange.StartDate.HasValue)
    {
        range = range.Where(o => o.StartDateTime >= dataRange.StartDate.Value);
    }

    if (dataRange.EndDate.HasValue)
    {
        range = range.Where(o => o.StartDateTime <= dataRange.EndDate.Value);
    }

    var result = range.ToList();
    return Ok(result);
}

This works (when tested with swagger UI), now in the ASP.NET web client, I need to filter the records by a specified date ranged.  The front-end action (controller) on the client looks like this
    [HttpPost("GetRange")]
public IActionResult GetRange(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
{
    string baseUrl = _config.GetValue<string>("ApiSettings:BaseUrl");
    //create a list for the range of products
    List<CourseViewModel> productList = new List<CourseViewModel>();
 
    HttpResponseMessage response = _client.GetAsync($"{baseUrl}/Course/GetRange?StartDate={startdate}&&EndDate={enddate}").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        //deserialized the "data"
        productList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CourseViewModel>>(data);
    }


    return View(productList);
}

Then added the two input fields and submit button to the razor page (index.cshtml)
<form method="post">
    Startdate : <input type="datetime" name="startdate" />
    Enddate : <input type="datetime" name="enddate" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />

    <table class="table">

<!—Code to display headers and the data not shown -->
</table>
</form>

Both backend and frontend have a class DateRange
public DateTime? startdate { get; set; }
 public DateTime? enddate { get; set; }

When starting application (API and client), razor page (index.cshtml) is populates corretly with all records; however, when trying to filter by starDate and EndDate, still does not retrieve data.
Still getting a 405 error when I click "submit".
Do I even need to encapsulate the table with a "form tag?
What tells the submit button what Action to execute?
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

405 error, method not allowed, you are sending the request as POST, but your API action is a GET method. Either you need to change the form element with method="GET" or change the API action attribute to [HttpPost].

Your API action:
public IActionResult GetRange(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)

expects to receive a GET request. But you are posting the form as POST.
You should perform either:
Approach 1: Change the <form> element with method="GET".
<form method="GET">
    ....
</form>

Approach 2: Apply [HttpPost] attribute to the API action
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetRange(DateRange dateRange)
{
    DateTime startdate = dateRange.startdate;
    DateTime enddate = dateRange.enddate;

    ...
}

public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime startdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime enddate { get; set; }
}


Your REST API is HttpPost & you send request from front-end project using HttpGet method, That's why you are facing issue with status code 405 - Method not allowed.
Try this code :
[HttpPost("GetRange")]
public IActionResult GetRange(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
{
    string baseUrl = _config.GetValue<string>("ApiSettings:BaseUrl");
    //create a list for the range of products
    List<CourseViewModel> productList = new List<CourseViewModel>();

    // NOTE: Modify GetAsync to PostAsync & Pass empty JSON body.
    HttpResponseMessage response = _client.PostAsync($"{baseUrl}/Course/GetRange?StartDate={startdate}&&EndDate={enddate}", new StringContent("{}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        //deserialized the "data"
        productList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CourseViewModel>>(data);
    }
    return View(productList);
}


After trying all suggestions and unable to make it work, this is what I did and works for me.
-Created a new razor page call GetRange
-Modify index.cshtml as follows
<form asp-action="GetRange">
    Startdate : <input type="datetime"  name="startdate" />
    Enddate : <input type="datetime" name="enddate" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />

-Copy all the contents from index.cshtml to GetRange.cshtml
